# There is a sentence I can't fully understand. Check these things, please!

Tags: meaning

You become a cold, calculating creature who slips into a sort of mediocrity where you realize there is difference between your desired self and your actual self.

In the above sentence, some parts are understood and some parts are not. 
First, is this grammatically correct English? Second, would you paraphrase this for me?

I'm having the most trouble with the words *become*, *slips into*, and *where*.

Comment: Have you considered asking this question on English Language Learners http://ell.stackexchange.com/?  You say you understand part of the sentence, so please indicate which part you do understand and what you think it means.

Comment: the parts I understand the whole sentence except three words

Comment: 'become','slips into','where'

Comment: become and where grammatically don't get

Comment: slips into don't get as meaning in the sentence.

Comment: Stack Exchange prefers that you edit key responses into the question, so that it may be better answered. Please take a look at the [edit history](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/320725/revisions) to see what I've done (because this question was about to be closed because you didn't edit in your response of which words you were having trouble with, which needed to be in the question in the first place. Because there is a "close reason" for proofreading questions that don't state *exactly* what the problem is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your sentence with *become*, *slips into*, and *where* replaced.

> You [turn into] a cold, calculating creature [who lets themselves slip] into a sort of mediocrity [and in your mind] you realize there is {a} difference between your desired self and your actual self.

I'll head off the follow up question, as I myself had to look up *mediocrity* to narrow down the author's intent.

> You turn into a cold, calculating creature who [ has convinced themselves that they are mediocre; not living up to their full potential ] and in your mind you realize there is a difference between your desired self and your actual self.

If there are any further questions about the context, I'd have to point you to Philosophy.SE

Comment: Just don't migrate the question.... ;)

Comment: Now I'm starting to understand what you comment. Thanks for all your  help.